# Running Docker on Raspbian -- need to install raspberrypi-kernel-headers

Tags: kernel, docker

I am running an image that's running on several amd64 servers and on a brand new RPI4.

One of the things that's needed are the kernel headers.

The image is being pulled is `FROM debian:stable-slim`. On Debian this command works fine `apt-get install -y linux-headers-$(uname -r)` but that doesn't work on Raspbian.

I could modify the script to install `raspberrypi-kernel-headers` instead -- but that's not available on Debian.

What would be the best way to install RPi kernel headers in a Debian container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the raspbian and rpi repos.

```
echo "deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ buster main contrib non-free rpi" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/rpi.list
echo "deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ buster main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/rpi.list
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 9165938D90FDDD2E
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 82B129927FA3303E
```

I execute a different run.sh from my Dockerfile depending on the arch of the machine.

That works, so all good.